# Promise called too early

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, resize, promise

When the file is an JPG it's created before the response is returned (to display the resized picture in the browser). But when it's an PNG it returns before it has written the PNG resulting in a crash of the Node.Js server because it can't create a ReadStream for something that does not exist:

Resizer Call

```
else {
    resizer
        .resizeHandler(filepath, parsedUrl, fullDestinationPath)
        .then(function () {
            return self.send(response, 200, {'Content-Type': mime.lookup(fullDestinationPath)}, fs.createReadStream(fullDestinationPath));
        });
}
```

Resizing

```
Resizer.prototype.resizeThenCrop = function(filepath, parsedUrl, fullDestinationPath){
    return Jimp.read(filepath)
        .then(function (picture) {
            var cropWidth = parsedUrl.query.w,
                cropHeight = parsedUrl.query.h;
            calculate(picture, parsedUrl);
                picture.resize(parseInt(parsedUrl.query.w), parseInt(parsedUrl.query.h))
                    .crop(parseInt((parsedUrl.query.w - cropWidth) / 2), parseInt((parsedUrl.query.h - cropHeight) / 2), parseInt(cropWidth), parseInt(cropHeight))
                    .quality(parseInt(parsedUrl.query.quality))
                    .write(fullDestinationPath)
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
};
```

Send

```
Router.prototype.send = function (response, code, headers, data) {
    response.statusCode = code;

    if (headers) {
        for (var index in headers) {
            if (headers.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                response.setHeader(index, headers[index]);
            }
        }
    }

    if (data instanceof Stream) {
        data.pipe(response);
    } else {
        response.end(data);
    }
};
```

**But maybe it cannot handle PNG's or it has an error trying to resize it?** I've tested and confirmed this is not the case simply by changing the code to this:

```
else {
        resizer
            .resizeHandler(filepath, parsedUrl, fullDestinationPath)
            .then(function () {
                //return self.send(response, 200, {'Content-Type': mime.lookup(fullDestinationPath)}, fs.createReadStream(fullDestinationPath));
            });
    }
```

Now it returns nothing and my browser will be waiting forever since it doesn't give a response back. But it does create the file in the folder like it does with a JPG meaning that it does work. When the createReadStream is called before the resized file is actually created it results in a crash because the file doesn't exist. The file also doesn't get created then because the server creating it has stopped. The error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/pngbla_w512_h53_q80.png'
    at Error (native)
```

What can I do to make it work properly for my PNG? And why doesn't it work for my PNG files even if for some JPG files it takes 20 seconds because it's resized to a big resolution.

EDIT: I've tried for multiple sizes even if resizing would be almost instant ~5ms, the response will still be called before with a PNG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it started writing the JPG already and the BMP only when it's done, I solved it using a callback changing the code to:

```
Resizer.prototype.resizeThenCrop = function(filepath, parsedUrl, fullDestinationPath){
    return Jimp.read(filepath)
        .then(function (picture) {
            var cropWidth = parsedUrl.query.w,
                cropHeight = parsedUrl.query.h;
            calculate(picture, parsedUrl);

            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                picture.resize(parseInt(parsedUrl.query.w), parseInt(parsedUrl.query.h))
                    .crop(parseInt((parsedUrl.query.w - cropWidth) / 2), parseInt((parsedUrl.query.h - cropHeight) / 2), parseInt(cropWidth), parseInt(cropHeight))
                    .quality(parseInt(parsedUrl.query.quality))
                    .write(fullDestinationPath, function(err) {
                        if(err) {
                            return reject(err);
                        }

                        return resolve(fullDestinationPath);
                    });
            });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
};
```

The problem was that picture.resize didn't return a promise so it continued without waiting for .write to be done.